# Precise Failure property of Half-minimum distance decoder

Tags: coding-theory

By half min decoder, I mean a decoder that is 1) efficient 2) always corrects if there are less than or equal to d/2 errors and 3) always fails if there are more than d/2 errors. Can such hypothetical decoders exist?

Say we have a $q$-ary code of length $n$ and minimum distance $d$. If one uses a traditional half-minimum distance decoder that corrects all errors of upto $\lfloor\frac{d}{2}\rfloor$ precisely, then is the corrected vector $\underline{ALWAYS}$ wrong if the number of errors in the vector before correction is $\lfloor\frac{d}{2}\rfloor + 1$? If not, then for what fraction of error vectors beyond half min distance does the decoder always fail?

Comment: Can you give a precise definition of the *traditional half-minimum distance decoder*? There are a few decoders you could mean here, and I'm not sure which you're talking about.

Comment: By half min decoder, I mean a decoder that is 1) efficient 2) always corrects if there are less than or equal to d/2 errors and 3) always fails if there are more than d/2 errors. Can such hypothetical decoders exist?

Comment: No, not in the general case. Consider the code $C = \{ 0000, 1111 \}$. For this code, $\lfloor \frac{d}{2} \rfloor = 2$. Suppose you send $0000$ and two errors occur, giving you $0101$. Suppose you send $1111$ and two errors occur, giving you $0101$. In both cases, $\le \lfloor \frac{d}{2} \rfloor$ errors occured, but you have no way of knowing whether $0000$ or $1111$ was sent.

Comment: However, ignoring efficiency, such a decoder always exists for $\le \lfloor \frac{d-1}{2} \rfloor$ errors: If there is a unique codeword in a $\lfloor \frac{d-1}{2} \rfloor$-sphere around the received word, decode to that codeword. Otherwise, fail.

Comment: I'm a bit curious. Why would you want to guarantee a failure? Also, if you have a decoding algorithm for correcting up to $[(d-1)/2]$ errors, surely such a decoding algorithm can always check in the end, whether the number of errors it corrected (if it was successful in the first place) exceeded a prescribed bound $d'$ and report FAILURE instead? Or did I misunderstand what you are asking about?

Comment: IMHO the interesting decoding algorithms are those that seek to go BEYOND $(d-1)/2$. These often output a list of codewords within a given radius of the received one (uniqueness is no longer guaranteed, so there may be two or more codewords on the list, and sometimes the list may be empty). Look up Madhu Sudan's algorithm for Reed-Solomon codes (it can be extended to AG-codes).

Comment: Or did you mean a decode like that of a Hamming code, that will ALWAYS either accept the received word (if it's a codeword) or flip a single bit to turn it into one? (which was the wrong thing to do, if two or more errors occurred) Such decoders do not exist for all codes. The reason is that the *covering radius* of the code is usually larger than $(d-1)/2$.

Comment: Take an Algebraic geometric code of genus $g$. Then your minimum distance falls between $[n−k+1−g,n−k+1]$. Say one chooses $t=\frac{d−1}{2}−1$. Can one design a true polynomial time $t$-bounded distance decoder for this case? Ideally the code should correctly decode between $0$ and $t$ errors and produce wrong codeword between $d-t$ and $d$ errors and produce failure between $t$ and $d-t$ errors. Can such a $t$-bounded distance decoder exist which runs in polynomial time and fails (and we know it fails) in polynomial time for a given AG code?

Answer (score 2):

There are several misconceptions in your notions about what happens
with bounded-distance decoders, and especially in the case
when the number of errors is exactly equal to $\frac{d}{2}$ where $d$
is the minimum distance of the code.

Suppose that $\mathbf c$ is the transmitted codeword and $\mathbf r$
is the received word. 
By definition, a $t$-error-correcting bounded-distance decoder produces the
unique codeword 
$\hat{\mathbf{c}}$ (if 
such a codeword exists) that is at distance $t$ or less from the received
word $\mathbf{r}$. Here, $t \leq \frac{d-1}{2}$ where $d$ is the minimum
distance of the code.

- If $t$ or fewer errors have occurred, then 
  the codeword $\hat{\mathbf{c}}$ that the decoder produces 
  is $\mathbf c$, and the decoder has operated exactly as we
  want it to operate: it has determined the transmitted codeword
  correctly.
- If $d-t$ or more errors have occurred, there *might* be 
  a different (unique) codeword $\hat{\mathbf{c}}$ that is
  at distance $t$ or less from $\mathbf r$, and in this case,
  the decoder will produce $\hat{\mathbf{c}}$. This event is
  called a *decoder error.* The occurrence of such an event
  is *not* something that the decoder can *detect,* and the
  wrong codeword is thus sent on to its destination.

  It is also possible that there is no codeword at distance $t$
  or less from $\mathbf r$, and in this case, the decoder will
  not produce a codeword at all, but will provide an indication
  to the effect that there is no codeword at distance $t$ or less
  from $\mathbf r$.
- If $t < \frac{d-1}{2}$, then in the "no-man's-land" 
  where the number of errors is more than $t$ and less than $d-t$, 
  the $t$-error-correcting bounded-distance decoder
  will *always* fail and indicate that there is no codeword
  within distance $t$ of the received word. It might be
  that the actual number of errors is smaller than $\frac{d-1}{2}$
  and so $\mathbf c$ is the unique codeword that is closest
  to the received word $\mathbf r$. It might even be that the
  decoder is able to determine that this is the case, but since
  it is constrained to correct no more than $t$ errors, it
  nonetheless indicates that $\mathbf r$ cannot be decoded
  into a codeword at distance $t$ or less from $\mathbf r$.
- When $d$ is an even number, and exactly $\frac{d}{2}$ errors
  have occurred, there *might* be *two* codewords that are at distance
  $\frac{d}{2}$ from the received word: the codeword $\mathbf{c}$ actually transmitted and another codeword $\hat{\mathbf c}$. Thus, a
  $\frac{d}{2}$-error-correcting bounded distance decoder does not
  exist in the sense that no decoder can *guarantee* that
  *all* possible patterns of $\frac{d}{2}$ or fewer errors will result in the
  transmitted codeword being determined correctly.
  Variations of decoders such as *list* decoders that produce
  a *list* of most likely transmitted
  codewords can be used in such cases,
  but these are not called bounded-distance decoders
  in the sense described above.

Comment: Your answer is interesting especially the "no-man's"land part. Is your decoder poly time? Is there a reference for your decoder. Thankyou for the help.

Comment: Actually part of this question came from one of your papers where you describe the notion of a well behaved bch decoder I believe.

Comment: Is there a reference for fast(polynomial time) true "t-error-correcting bounded-distance decoders" for a general linear code and $t$ can be flexibly fixed to any value less than or equal to $\lfloor\frac{d-1}{2}\rfloor$?

Comment: A canonical decoder for a Reed-Muller code of length $n = 2^m$ will decode (whether correctly or incorrectly) in the presence of any number of errors. This is a threshold decoder: the value of a data bit is computed $d$ times using $d$ different equations that operate on the bits in the received word (and thus possibly erroneous bits), and the value of the data is taken as the _majority_ of the values obtained by the $d$ calculations. If $\frac{d}{2}$ errors have occurred, _half_ the calculations might say $1$, the other half $0$. So, flip a coin to break a tie, or always choose $1$, etc.

Comment: RM codes are special. Take an Algebraic geometric code of genus $g$. Then your minimum distance falls between $[n-k+1-g,n-k+1]$. Say one chooses $t=\frac{d-1}{2}-1$. Can one design a true polynomial time bounded distance decoder for this case?